# Field validation with rulesetName defined?

Tags: wpf, validation, enterprise-library

I have an item to validate.

I have a domain like this :

```
[NotNullValidator]
public string UserName
{
   get;
   set;
}

[NotNullValidator(Ruleset="Validation_Test"]
public string UserAddress
{
   get;
   set;
}
```

Now, on my XAML code, I realize the binding with my `DataContext`, and, with the `IDataError` interface, I can realize the field validation :

```
<TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding UserName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />

<TextBox Width="100" Text="{Binding UserAddress, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

However, only the first validation works. I think it's due to the ruleset that I defined.

Is it possible to define the ruleset name in order to do the validation (by code or by xaml)?

Comment: can you post your code for NotNullValidator?

Comment: NotNullValidator is an attribute available on the EnterpriseLibrary 5.0